# Hyperledger framework for Mobile Application?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-iroha

Which framework is better to develop blockchain application for mobile.
Fabric or Iroha, what are the reason behind it ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyperledger Sawtooth, another blockchain platform, has a Swift SDK (for iOS apps) and a Java SDK (for Android apps).

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion Iroha is more suitable for building blockchain applications for mobile because Iroha is written in c++.

Iroha is a distributed ledger project, that aims to provide a development environment where C++ and mobile application developers could contribute to Hyperledger. The project seeks to complement Fabric, Sawtooth, and other potential projects, being a framework with pre-defined set of commands, permissions and queries that can be used with various client libraries to easily create applications for desktop and mobile platforms.

Key Characteristics
Permissioned network; written in C++; Client libraries in Java, Python, JS, Swift; BFT consensus algorithm YetAnotherConsensus (YAC); ready-to-use set of commands and queries, Multi-signature transactions.

It takes a minute to run iroha network. you can start your network by just copy and pasting this docker command in your terminal.
**docker network create iroha-network**

Whereas you can also use hyperledger fabric to build applications but the documentation is still not clear. you will find broken links and development on fabric will take more time.

Comment: Iroha 2 is written in Rust